# RadioButtons in Ui-Grid

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid, bootstrap-accordion

I am using Ui-grid in angularjs. I would like to add radiobutton as first column in the grid and also need to remove some particular columns from each like Id , IsDeleted etc. Following is the plunker I am using. I have to check on a button click that atleast one of the products row is selected. Can someone help me in accomplishing this.

Following is my plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/ecOJ4IJX384E7MHkCzfR?p=preview

Following is my html code

```
  <accordion-group heading="{{product.TypeName}}">
    <br />
    <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-auto-resize class="grid"></div>
  </accordion-group>
```

Comment: did you solve this? im having a similar problem